# Pronunciation of ‘monotonous'

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I am just curious why 'monotonous' is pronounced ***mo·not·o·nous*** and not ***mono.tonous*** following the Greek origin of the word as *mono + tone.* *Mono* and *tone* could be pronounced alone and actually they constitute the word monotonous.

Comment: Isn't *monotonus* accented on the second syllable [in Latin](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Latin/Pronunciation_Stress#:~:text=In%20Latin%2C%20the%20stress%20on,antepenultimate%20syllable%2C%20or%20antepenult.&text=If%20the%20vowel%20in%20the,stress%20goes%20on%20the%20penult.), where many words are pronounced on the third-from-last syllable?

Comment: Lots of English words can be both noun and verb, and often they're distinguished by the fact that the ***noun*** form starts with a *stressed* syllable. Maybe that has a bearing on why we put stress on the first syllable of the noun ***monotone***, whereas for the ***adjectival*** usage ***monotonous*** the stress comes on the ***second*** syllable. (Just don't ask me where the noun ***monotony*** fits in there! :)

Comment: Even the Greek is accented on the second syllable: [μονότονος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=mono%2F-tonos&la=greek&can=mono%2F-tonos0&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:alphabetic%20letter=*m:entry%20group=86:entry=mono/tonos&i=1#lexicon), adj., "of one tone." Greeks did not use the accent to highlight a word's anatomy or etymology.

Comment: You pronounce it as monotonously as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phonetic syllabification corresponding to "monotonous" ("mo.not.on.ous") is  /mə 'nɒt ən əs/. This is the "leisurely" pronunciation; in most speech occurrences it would be /mə 'nɒt n əs/. The reason for not having "mono.tonous" as the syllabification is for one that there can be only one single phonetic vowel per phonetic syllable and for two  that words of three syllables or more, ending in "*ous*" not preceded by e or i or more than one consonant* are stressed on the third syllable from the end, bar exceptions (desirous, …).

- can.'tank.er.ous, *'ad.ult* **but** a 'dult er ous, ad.'vent.ur.ous,
  'am.our.ous, a.'nal.og.ous, a.'nom.al.ous, a.'non.ym.ous, 'ard.u.ous, a.'ssid.u.ous,
  a'synch.ron.ous, au.'ton.om.ous, *bar.'bar.i.an* **but** 'barb.ar.ous, 'blas.phem.ous, *'carn.i.vore* **but** car.'niv.er.ous, 'cav.ern.ous, *'circ.u.it* **but** cir.'cu.it.ous, 'cred.ul.ous, 'dec.or.ous, *'err.or* **but** e'rron.e.ous, 'fat.u.ous, 'garr.ul.ous, *'gel.a.tine* **but** ge'lat.in.ous, 'glam.or.ous, *'glut.en.* **and** 'glut.in.ous, 'glutton/'glutt.on.ous, *im.ˌpet.u.'os.it.y* **but** im.'pet.u.ous, *'in.cest* **but** in.'cest.u.ous, …

The principles of pronunciation cited, except for the third-syllable-from-the-end pattern can be verified in the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* and *An Introduction to The Pronunciation of English* by A.C. Gimson and Susan Ramsaran. The third syllable rule is deducible from an examination of the dictionary just mentioned.

*A research by [user Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541987/pronunciation-of-monotonous/542001?noredirect=1#comment1329105_542001) gives the following examples.
*disastrous, enormous, momentous, tremendous*
We can add "*stupendous*" and *"portentous"* but there are at least two exceptions: "*ludicrous*" and "*marvellous*".

Comment: *disastrous, enormous, momentous, tremendous.*

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because of English stress patterns. English has very complex stress patterns. In most cases, the [antepenultimiate syllable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antepenultimate) (third last syllable) tends to be stressed.

The main stress often moves to the antepenult when the suffix *[**-ous**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ous)* is appended to a word.

**Examples:**

- Glorious -> /**ˈɡlɔː**.ri.əs/
- Monotonous -> /mə**ˈnɒt**.ən.əs/
- Dangerous -> /**ˈdeɪn**.dʒ<sup>ə</sup>r.əs/
- Adventurous -> /əd**ˈven**.tʃər.əs/
- Furious -> /**ˈfjʊə**.ri.əs/
- Humorous -> /**ˈhjuː**.mə.rəs/
- Contiguous -> /kən**ˈtɪɡ**.ju.əs/
- Ludicrous -> /**ˈluː**.dɪ.krəs/

*Monotonous* follows the same pattern and I don't think it has anything to do with the prefix it's derived from.

Compare *monotonic* /ˌmɒn.ə**ˈtɒn**.ɪk/ -- Words that end with the suffix *-ic* are often stressed on the penult. So I guess it has to do with English stress patterns.

And when *monotonous* is stressed on the antepenult, the vowels in the unstressed syllables get laxed as usual. Therefore, it's pronounced /mə**ˈnɒt**.ən.əs/.

However, there are some words that have only two syllables, and words that have three syllables but the primary stress moves to the [penult](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penult) (second last syllable) when the suffix *-ous* is appended:

- Disastrous -> /dɪ**ˈzɑːs**.trəs/
- Tremendous -> /trɪ**ˈmen**.dəs/
- Stupendous -> /stjuː**ˈpen**.dəs/
- Momentous -> /mə**ˈmen**.təs/
- Enormous -> /ə**ˈnɔːr**.məs/

There's a fairly regular pattern for these words: *if the penultimate syllable is [heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable_weight), it’s stressed; if the penultimate syllable is [light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable_weight), the antepenultimate syllable is stressed* (it also holds true for most of the words that are stressed on the antepenult i.e. the penultimate syllable is light and the antepenultimate syllable is heavy).

- Light -> short vowel and no [coda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Coda).
- Heavy -> long vowel or diphthong and/or has a coda.

In the above words, the emboldened syllables are heavy, hence stressed.

There may be loads of exceptions, however.

---

**Update (August 20, 2020):**

Luigi Burzio in his book [Principles of English stress](https://books.google.com/books/about/Principles_of_English_Stress.html?id=QfIwmPCxmZoC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (chapter 3) writes:

> It has long been known that English lexicon does not exhibit a uniform metrical behaviour, but breaks down into two major subsets, whose rightmost stress conforms to either of (1) or (2).
>
> (1)
>
> **a.** Heavy penultimate, if there is one:
>
> agénda, appéndix, horí:zon.
>
>
> **b.** Otherwise, antepenultimate:
>
> américa, ásterisk
>
> (2)
>
> **a.** Superheavy final, if there is one:
>
> prevént, decí:de
>
>
> **b.** Otherwise, penultimate:
>
> inhábit, imágine

Head over to [Principles of English stress](https://books.google.com/books/about/Principles_of_English_Stress.html?id=QfIwmPCxmZoC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) for more explanation.