# Stressed syllables in "ostentatious" and "adventurous"

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I have been confused by the accented syllables in the words "ostentatious" and "adventurous". Although both of them have the same number of syllables, they are accented on different syllables. And both are adjectives. I am trying to find a rule that determines where to put the accent on a word.

**Adventurous:**  US  /əd**ˈven**.tʃɚ.əs/

UK  /əd**ˈven**.tʃər.əs/

**Ostentatious:** US  /ˌɑː.stən**ˈteɪ**.ʃəs/

UK  /ˌɒs.ten**ˈteɪ**.ʃəs/

As you can see both have different syllables accented.

Is it because their nouns have accent on the same syllables?
Ostentation and adventure??

Comment: The rule in English is to expect that our rules have generous exceptions.  Experience will tutor you, as will reading the classics and selecting who to model your speech after.

Comment: Generally speaking, there are no rules.  But note that "adventure" has a new syllable added when converted to an adjective, whereas "ostentation" doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pronunciation of ‘monotonous'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/542113/365490) --- I've explained it in my answer. *When the penult is heavy, it's stressed. When the penult is light, the antepenult is stressed*. It's a fairly regular pattern.... there may be exceptions, however.

Comment: That particular rule is inherited from Latin, which used it on every word. English only uses it on certain borrowed words, mostly from Latin. Spanish still has a descendant of the Latin rule, shortened by a syllable. But of course English has [undergone  other changes](https://www.google.com/search?q=trisyllabic+laxing), and borrowed lots of words from other languages, and borrowed from many dialects of Latin, for that matter. So there are no rules that work. You shouldn't expect any consistency, any more than English spelling is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to explain their stress patterns.

One way is to say that it is based on the stress patterns of related nouns, as you said: *ostentation* and *adventure.*

Another way is to look at the exact form of the ending of the word.

***Ostentatious* ends in *-ious.* Words ending in *-ious* are pretty much always stressed on the immediately preceding syllable** (I don't know of any exception). (This rule applies regardless of whether *-ious* is pronounced as one or two syllables.) Incidentally, the same stress pattern applies to words ending *-ial,* *-ian* or *-iate,* as well as *-eous, -eal, -ean, -eate.*

***Adventurous* ends in *-ous* preceded by a single consonant letter.** Words of more than two syllables that end like that can be stressed on the syllable immediately before *-ous* (as in *intravenous* or *heterozygous*), but are more often stressed on the preceding (third to last) syllable: *carnivorous, humorous, ominous, frivolous.*

While it's true that the stress pattern usually corresponds to the weight of the second-to-last syllable, it's a little unclear whether this explains the stress pattern since you could make an argument that stressed vowels are lengthened in this context (rather than long vowels being stressed).

Comment: One former exception to the emergent rule is that OED v2 had *ˈsuperconscious* with primary stress on the word’s first syllable. However, OED v3 now demotes that to secondary stress and moves the primary stress  to where you'd expect, yielding /ˌsupərˈkɑnʃəs/. This may vary by speech community.

Comment: @tchrist: I think that pronunciation probably represents stress as a compound noun "super-conscious" with primary stress on the first element and secondary stress on the second element. Compare "supermarket", "supergiant",  "superpower", "supermodel". "Superego" can also have that stress pattern.

Comment: All these words follow the pattern I've explained in [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/542113/365490), don't they?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: These two specific words do. For *-tious* words in general, it depends on how you count syllables. If you count *-tious* as two syllables (even though it's very often pronounced as one), then words ending in *-tious* follow the antepenult stress rule. If you count it as one syllable, then words ending in *-itious* (such as *adventitious, superstitious, fictitious*) don't follow that rule: they are stressed on the second-to-last syllable even though the vowel is short /ɪ/.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation